# Querying mongo documents by clock range - forward and reverse

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Business case: I don't want to retrieve users who don't want to be retrieved during a range of hours in a day e.g., off-work hours.

On a schema close to this

```
{
  'name': String,
  'from': Number, // 800 (8:00 AM)
  'to': Number, // 1700 (5:00 PM)
  ...
}
```

I'm using an aggregation to fetch users while also unwinding subdocument arrays among other operations. The basic search criteria is in the `$match` operator which is like this.

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    // some aggregation stuff
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { 'from': { $lte: currentTime },
        { 'to': { $gte: currentTime }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

**Question:**
How can I allow users to setup reverse ranges ***also***? Like 8PM to 8AM. How can I write a query that will help with this? No hair left to pull for today.

Answer (score 1):

For a "normal" range like 9am to 5pm, the query condition is

```
{ "$match" : { "from" : { "$lte" : ct }, "to" : { "$gte" : ct } } }
```

(`$and` is unnecessary because it is implied) while for a "reverse" range like 8pm to 8am, the query condition is

```
{ "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "from" : { "$gte" : ct } }, { "to" : { "$lte" : ct } }] } }
```

The logic is different for the two types of ranges, so you ought to add new fields for reverse ranges:

```
{
    "name" : "Jerry",
    "rfrom" : 2000,
    "rto" : 800
}
```

and then either do aggregations, with matches

```
{ "$match" : { "from" : { "$lte" : ct }, "to" : { "$gte" : ct } } }

{ "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "rfrom" : { "$gte" : ct } }, { "rto" : { "$lte" : ct } }] } }
```

or one aggregation with the disjunction of the two `$match` conditions:

```
{ "$match" : { "$or" : [
    { "from" : { "$lte" : ct }, "to" : { "$gte" : ct } },
    { "$or" : [{ "rfrom" : { "$gte" : ct } }, { "rto" : { "$lte" : ct } }] }
] } }
```

Alternatively, there could exist a clever way to store your time ranges that would work for "normal" and "reverse" ranges in one query, but I couldn't think of it in 5 minutes.